# Como leer una lista de 1000 elementos desde un archivo txt en python para despues ordenarla con Quicksort

Tags: python

```
def leeLista():
    arreglo=[]
    a=int(raw_input("Ingresa el tamano del arreglo: "))


    for i in range(0,a):
        arreglo.append(int(raw_input("Ingresa los valores %d : " % i)))
        #en lugar de ingresarlos los quiero extraer de un archivo txt 
    pos=int(raw_input("Selecciona el pivote: "))
    return arreglo
```

Comment: Que limitadores entre elementos tiene tu txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice Jorge Arturo en su comentario, depende de los limitadores que tengas en tu archivo txt. Suponiendo que cada valor esté separado por un salto de línea en tu archivo entonces sería algo así como lo siguiente.

```
arch = open('archivo.txt', 'r')

for linea in arch:
    arreglo.append(int(linea))

arch.close()
```

Para que esto sea aplicable también todas las líneas de tu archivo deben ser valores enteros.

Comment: gracias me sirvo tu aportación

Comment: de nada, qué bien que te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

abres el archivo con `open`  luego lees el texto con `read()` y liego convertes tu `string` en un `list` con `split()`, puedes agregar tu separador dentro de split:

```
file = open(“testfile.text”, “r”) 
text = file.read() 
items = text.split(",")
```

en mi ejemplo el texto seria algo como "a,b,c,d" y `split` lo convierte a ["a","b","c","d"]

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios los tomare en cuenta me sirvo bastante

Answer (score 0):

¿Como es el formato del archivo? voy a asumir que es un archivo plano con un valor por línea y lo que buscas es cargar esto en una lista.

```
def read_file(file):
    """Lee un archivo de texto y devuelve una lista con sus lineas"""
    lista = []
    with open(file) as procfile:
      for line in procfile:
        lista.append(line.strip())
    return lista
```

Ahora si el archivo tiene una sola línea con valores separados por ',', se puede hacer esto:

```
def read_file(file):
    """Lee un archivo de texto y devuelve una lista"""
    with open(file) as procfile:
      line = procfile.readline()
      return [i for i in line.split(',')]
```

Comment: Gracias por la aportación

Answer (score 0):

```
def quicksort(arreglo,izq,der):
    i=izq
    j=der
    piv=arreglo[(izq + der)/2]

    while( i <= j ):
        while arreglo[i]<piv and j<=der:
            i=i+1
        while piv<arreglo[j] and j>izq:
            j=j-1
        if i<=j:
            aux = arreglo[i]; 
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[j]; 
            arreglo[j] = aux;
            i=i+1;  
            j=j-1;

        if izq < j:
          quicksort( arreglo, izq, j );
    if i < der:
        quicksort( arreglo, i, der );

def imprimeLista(arreglo,tam):
    for i in range(0,tam): print arreglo[i],



def leeLista():
    arreglo=[]
    a=int(raw_input("Ingresa el tamano del arreglo: "))

    #for i in range(0,a):
     #   arreglo.append(int(raw_input("Ingresa los valores %d : " % i)))

    arch = open('or.txt', 'r')

    for linea in arch:
        arreglo.append(linea.strip())

    arch.close()    

    pos=int(raw_input("Selecciona el pivote: "))
    return arreglo

A=leeLista()
tiempo_inicial = time()
quicksort(A,0,len(A)-1)
tiempo_final = time()
tiempo_ejecucion = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial
print'El tiempo de ejecucion fue ::', tiempo_ejecucion
imprimeLista(A,len(A))
```

este es mi codigo pero no hace el ordenamiento  solo imprime el arreglo tal cual

Resultado:

```
El tiempo de ejecucion fue :: 2.69412994385e-05
2,24,3,26,21,1, 4, 5, 29,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 30,16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25,  27, 28,11
```

Comment: Agon esto es una nueva pregunta. el apartado de respuestas es solo para respuestas a al pregunta actual. Por otro lado, si alguna respuesta te ha sido útil, por favor, reconoce el esfuerzo de los usuarios que te responden y [acepta la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas). Esta es la forma que hay en [es.so] de agradecer, además, ayudas a otros usuarios con el mismo problema a encontrar respuestas útiles. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por las observaciones las tomare en cuenta mas adelante